# On macOS: Microsoft Edge Canary keep showing me "This page is having a probIem" when browsing pages on GitHub

Tags: macos, microsoft-edge

As title.

MacOS version:

```
13.5 (22G74)
```

Edge version:

```
Version 117.0.1994.0 (Official build) Canary (arm64)
```

When I try to browse either the https://github.com/notifications or any GitHub repo, it just redirects itself to this "This page is having a problem" page:

[image]

Comment: I intentionally misspell the word "problem" in my title because StackExchange disallows me to use the word "problem" in a "good" title.

Comment: Oh I'm stupid, I just use the capital i to replace the lowercase L and make it looks better :)